# How to whitelist a website on facebook?

Tags: facebook, web, whitelist, sense

Recently, Facebook teamed up with Websense to filter malicious websites. One of the users on our site got this message - "teamed up with Websense to help protect you online.  The link you are trying to visit has been identified as potentially unsafe by our trusted partners." This is a pretty major site and the message above just seems odd to me.

I have tried to find ways to whitelist this website but I have been unsuccessful. How can I whitelist this website on Facebook?

Thanks

Comment: facebook basicly work together with http://www.mywot.com/ try to check your rating on this site.

Comment: The rating on that site looks good. In the high 80s. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably seen this but just incase you haven't

http://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/v76/filter_faqs/filter_faq_whitelist.aspx

Comment: I don't think that helps. The link that you gave me is to whitelist a URL to be accessed from behind a WebSense firewall. This is common for workplaces. The message that the user got was on the Facebook website itself.